# Measure the CPU time elapsed for a part of code in JAVA

Tags: java, time, cpu, elapsed

I'm currently trying to measure the real elapsed cpu time for a part of my code in java.
I read that to get the CPU time you have to use the

```
cpuTime = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
```

but in fact when I try to measure it in that piece of code, an error is thrown when the elapsed time is equal to zero..... (which it appears to me to be impossible with a nano-sec precision). The while loop can be big or can also very small (aout 10 instuctions min).

```
long startTime = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean()
                        .getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
// reset with seed solution for each neighborRule and
// each pivoting rule
t.setCurrentBestSolution(seedSolution);
while (t.chooseNextImprovingNeighborSolution(pivotingRule,
                        neighborRule));                 
long endTime = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean()
                    .getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
if (endTime - startTime == 0) {
    System.err.println(pivotingRule + ":" + neighborRule);
    System.err.println("END TIME:" + endTime);
    System.err.println("START TIME:" + startTime);
                }
```

Any idea ? Am I not using properly the CPUThread part ?
Should I use an external java benchmarker ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't accurately measure execution time more precisely than the ns. You have to build a loop or another way to make you code longer if you want to benchmark it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The methods of `System` and `Runtime` class will help you.
Take a look on:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

For example: You can use: `System.currentTimeMillis();` which returns the time in millisecond, before and after your program! (at the beginning or end of `main` method!)

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how Runtime or System can give me the CPU-time.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use an external java benchmarker ?

Yes please do. [Jprofiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) measures the real elapsed time among other useful metrics.

Comment: JProfiler mostly use for web-based software! I think nobody don't use it for `console` applications. `System` and `Runtime` class may help better. What do you think?

Comment: What gave you that idea ? I used it to profile plain java applications all the time. You just need to hook up the agent correctly on VM startup.

Comment: I'll try to see if JProfiler make it work.
Having 0 isn't so annoying but What's the goal of having nanosecond precision if you cannot measure it precisely.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: The trouble is that nanoTime() does not offer nano level accuracy. Just nano level precision. The update resolution of nanoTime() affects your results. A native DLL / SO should be able to work around that by using the highest precision native clock with a better update resolution. Let us know how it panned out when you're done.